# LINQ query having aggregation function and join condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following very simple query in SQL:

```
select Sum(m.unitPrice * mtp.units) charges 
from tbl_Medicines m, tbl_MedicineToPatient mtp 
where m.medicineId = mtp.medicineId and mtp.patientId = 1001
```

I need to convert this query to Linq to Entities query. I tried the following (which I know is wrong):

```
var varQuery = (from med in hmsdatabase.TblMedicines
              join medtopat in hmsdatabase.TblMedicineToPatients
              on med.MedicineId equals medtopat.MedicineId
              let jjj = new { med, medtopat}
              where medtopat.PatientId == 1001
              select jjj.Sum(med.UnitPrice * medtopat.Units)
              ).First();
```

I know it doesn't make sense. Any kind of help is appreciated. I have not been able to find a post which has a query that is in LINQ format, contains aggregate function, a join condition and (multiplication) operation on fields of two different tables.

Answer (score 2):

Should just be

```
var total = (from med in hmsdatabase.TblMedicines
                join medtopat in hmsdatabase.TblMedicineToPatients
                    on med.MedicineId equals medtopat.MedicineId
                where medtopat.PatientId == 1001
                select med.UnitPrice * medtopat.Units
                ).Sum();
```

Note that this returns a single value, not a collection.